# Run code before NestJs Decorators initialization

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

Are there ways to get data and save from another microservice before decorator initialization? As I understand decorators initialize even before bootstrap function is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decorators evaluate to regular JS code that is evaluated when the file is required. The only way to run something before the decorator, is to have that something higher in the file, or before that file is even required in another script. It'd be like having

```js
export const foo = () => {
  console.log('foo');
}

console.log('Here we are exporting foo');
```

And wanting to run something before the `console.log('Here we are exporting foo')`. The only way is to have what you want to run higher up in the file, or before this file is every required